# Regex: Regular expression for algorithmic operations with parentheses

Tags: regex, expression, parentheses

I need help to build a `regular expression` that accepts the basic arithmetic operations algorithm, but also allows `meter operations` on any number of parentheses

so far I have this expression:

```
^([(]*(-)?\d+(\.\d+)?[)]?)([(]?[-+/*%^]?\d+(\.\d+)?[)]*)+
```

It happens that the above expression accepts me without closing parenthesis or unopened (parentheses must go in pairs). 
I show the evidence that I have made, which is in the red box should not accept
http://regexr.com/38r4u

And I hope you can help me,

Thanks.

Comment: Which is your regexp implementation?  PHP, JavaScript, .NET, ...

Comment: regex implemented .NET (C#)

Comment: Then you can try using balancing groups (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition), which kind of implements recursion.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot parse a recursive structure using a regex. Use a parser instead.